# CSS zoom on hover is overlapping

Tags: html, css, zooming

A friend of mine uses a self-written CMS, where I can of course add CSS.
Zoom on hover for pictures is working by itself, but the predefined slider of the CMS causes the following images to overlap.
Can I resolve this in with my CSS? With "margin" I did not get further.

[Picture from overlapping images while zoom on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mulnx.jpg)

This is my CSS:

```
.img-hover-zoom {
overflow: hidden;
margin: auto;
}

.img-hover-zoom img {
transition: transform 1.0s ease;
cursor: grab;
}

.img-hover-zoom:hover img {
 transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: try `width: 100%` and `object-fit: cover` for `.img-hover-zoom img`. But it will be better if you make a reproducible example.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Have you looked at the image attached? There you can see the problem as a screenshot.

Comment: I only see the problem when I look at the code.

Comment: Can I ask you if you just look at the page then? I can only a little CSS and should only fix the problem, but not the rest of the page :-( 

https://gemuese-klaus.biodeliver.de/